# Gesture Recognition, Searching for Contacts

Tags: android

Can someone help me do a gesture recognition application in android. Where you will draw gestures of numbers and search for contact numbers that matches the gestures

Answer (score 1):

This is very good place to start with. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html